# Configuring HTACCESS in a sub directory

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I have an htaccess file in my main directory which redirects all top-level directories to a PHP file.

-> `/Loch` would go to `/profile.php?username=Loch`

But I also have a subdirectory, lets call it `test`

I need a rule in `test` that says, "any sub paths of my directory are actually GET variables.

For example, linking to `/test/hello/hi`

Should actually go to `/test/receiver.php?dataset=hello&action=hi`

However, when I use the following rules within an htaccess file in the `/test/` directory, it doesn't work this way (I get a 500 error).

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ /receiver.php?dataset=$1&action=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /receiver.php?dataset=$1
```

I hope I've provided enough info, please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expressions are not valid. `*` and `?` are both quantifiers which apply to the previous character, and so `*?` doesn't make sense. You probably want this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ /receiver.php?dataset=$1&action=$2
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /receiver.php?dataset=$1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Would upvote but I don't have enough points!